# Returning a item from an array in function

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a function that I want to return an UIImage but the UIImage must be in the array of UIImages I have created.

This works but I want it to fail if the item is not a part of the array.

```
private let screenImages: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "screen-1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "screen-2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "screen-3")]

private let getImage() -> (UIImage) {

    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenImages.count)))
    let image = screenImages[random]
    return image

}
```

So in the escaping of the function am I able to tell the function what kind of image it should return instead of UIImage.
Something like this

```
private let getImage() -> (UIImage in screenImages)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want it to fail if the item is not a part of the array'? `image` will be part of it..?

Comment: Is there a way to make sure a function will return an item of the screenImages array?

Comment: Your function does exactly that?

Comment: If you're referring to some function in general, then you can check it using something like `If screenImages.contains(x) {return x} else {[failure code]}`

Comment: Yes, that's what i was looking for thank you!!
Sorry that was a bit vague, but soon I'm adding an input to the function to see what the current screenImage is. Contains is what I need! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuri2060, answered my question.

What i was looking for was.

```
if screenImages.contains(x)
```